# Mongodb talend service keep down when trying to Access TDS campaign

Tags: mongodb, talend

Good day,

If I go to the TDS UI to access campaign list, it will load very long time.

And when I check the log, it showing mongoDb error. Thus I go to check the MongoDb log, no error found in the log, but the service just down.

```
[root@MYDVVLXRORNT01 ~]# systemctl list-units |grep talend-mongodb-8.0.1.service
● talend-mongodb-8.0.1.service                                                                     loaded failed failed    Talend MongoDB service
```

The log is as follow:

```
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=652835 port=27018 dbpath=/app/talend/801/mongodb/data/db 64-bit host=MYDVVLXRORNT01
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.9
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: fc525e2d9b0e4bceff5c2201457e564362909765
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/app/talend/801/mongodb/mongod.cfg", net: { bindIpAll: true, port: 27018 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/app/talend/801/mongodb/data/mongodb.pid" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/app/talend/801/mongodb/data/db" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/app/talend/801/mongodb/data/log/mongod.log" } }
2023-07-07T15:41:29.457+0800 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /app/talend/801/mongodb/data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2023-07-07T15:41:29.460+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /app/talend/801/mongodb/data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2023-07-07T15:41:29.460+0800 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2023-07-07T15:41:29.460+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=15419M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2023-07-07T15:41:30.359+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1688715690:359267][652835:0x7f004fdd1a40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 523/256 to 524/256
2023-07-07T15:41:30.359+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1688715690:359613][652835:0x7f004fdd1a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 523 through 524
2023-07-07T15:41:30.428+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1688715690:428781][652835:0x7f004fdd1a40], file:index-14-3177094335313338110.wt, txn-recover: Recovering log 524 through 524
2023-07-07T15:41:30.477+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1688715690:477497][652835:0x7f004fdd1a40], file:index-14-3177094335313338110.wt, txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2023-07-07T15:41:30.505+0800 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2023-07-07T15:41:30.685+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2023-07-07T15:41:30.685+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2023-07-07T15:41:30.685+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2023-07-07T15:41:30.685+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2023-07-07T15:41:30.787+0800 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/app/talend/801/mongodb/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2023-07-07T15:41:30.787+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27018
2023-07-07T15:41:32.923+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:42694 #1 (1 connection now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:32.923+0800 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:42694 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T15:41:34.875+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:42704 #2 (2 connections now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:34.876+0800 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:42704 conn2: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T15:41:35.987+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49146 #3 (3 connections now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:35.987+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49148 #4 (4 connections now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:35.987+0800 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49146 conn3: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.8.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T15:41:35.987+0800 I NETWORK  [conn4] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49148 conn4: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.8.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T15:41:36.028+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:42706 #5 (5 connections now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:36.029+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:42708 #6 (6 connections now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:36.029+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:42710 #7 (7 connections now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:36.029+0800 I NETWORK  [conn5] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:42706 conn5: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T15:41:36.029+0800 I NETWORK  [conn6] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:42708 conn6: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T15:41:36.029+0800 I NETWORK  [conn7] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:42710 conn7: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T15:41:36.056+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:42734 #8 (8 connections now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:36.056+0800 I NETWORK  [conn8] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:42734 conn8: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T15:41:38.368+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:42092 #9 (9 connections now open)
2023-07-07T15:41:38.368+0800 I NETWORK  [conn9] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:42092 conn9: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:00:54.470+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:34426 #10 (10 connections now open)
2023-07-07T16:00:54.470+0800 I NETWORK  [conn10] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:34426 conn10: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:00:54.474+0800 I ACCESS   [conn10] Successfully authenticated as principal tds-user on tds
2023-07-07T16:00:55.421+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37714 #11 (11 connections now open)
2023-07-07T16:00:55.421+0800 I NETWORK  [conn11] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:37714 conn11: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.8.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:00:55.424+0800 I ACCESS   [conn11] Successfully authenticated as principal session-user on sessions
2023-07-07T16:00:55.442+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37726 #12 (12 connections now open)
2023-07-07T16:00:55.442+0800 I NETWORK  [conn12] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:37726 conn12: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.8.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:00:55.443+0800 I ACCESS   [conn12] Successfully authenticated as principal session-user on sessions
2023-07-07T16:01:09.500+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:48688 #13 (13 connections now open)
2023-07-07T16:01:09.500+0800 I NETWORK  [conn13] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:48688 conn13: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:01:09.501+0800 I ACCESS   [conn13] Successfully authenticated as principal tds-user on tds
2023-07-07T16:01:09.526+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:48700 #14 (14 connections now open)
2023-07-07T16:01:09.526+0800 I NETWORK  [conn14] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:48700 conn14: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:01:09.527+0800 I ACCESS   [conn14] Successfully authenticated as principal tds-user on tds
2023-07-07T16:01:09.568+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:48702 #15 (15 connections now open)
2023-07-07T16:01:09.568+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:48716 #16 (16 connections now open)
2023-07-07T16:01:09.568+0800 I NETWORK  [conn15] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:48702 conn15: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:01:09.569+0800 I ACCESS   [conn15] Successfully authenticated as principal tds-user on tds
2023-07-07T16:01:09.569+0800 I NETWORK  [conn16] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:48716 conn16: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:01:09.570+0800 I ACCESS   [conn16] Successfully authenticated as principal tds-user on tds
2023-07-07T16:01:10.841+0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.122.160.171:48722 #17 (17 connections now open)
2023-07-07T16:01:10.841+0800 I NETWORK  [conn17] received client metadata from 10.122.160.171:48722 conn17: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "4.0.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./11.0.16.1+1-LTS" }
2023-07-07T16:01:10.842+0800 I ACCESS   [conn17] Successfully authenticated as principal tds-user on tds
2023-07-07T16:01:31.513+0800 I WRITE    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] update config.system.sessions command: { q: { _id: { id: UUID("9a892482-bf86-4754-8333-404de02b90b5"), uid: BinData(0, 94B72FB617F98A94E1094C66354967945CDACFD4FFFE13F9C80BE90E25EFA950) } }, u: { $currentDate: { lastUse: true }, $setOnInsert: { user: { name: "tds-user@tds" } } }, multi: false, upsert: true } planSummary: IDHACK keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 nMatched:0 nModified:0 upsert:1 keysInserted:2 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 28867, timeReadingMicros: 2098 } } 220ms
2023-07-07T16:01:31.761+0800 I WRITE    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] update config.system.sessions command: { q: { _id: { id: UUID("b8ac7e29-c984-4f0f-b04a-77ca107b5092"), uid: BinData(0, 94B72FB617F98A94E1094C66354967945CDACFD4FFFE13F9C80BE90E25EFA950) } }, u: { $currentDate: { lastUse: true }, $setOnInsert: { user: { name: "tds-user@tds" } } }, multi: false, upsert: true } planSummary: IDHACK keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 nMatched:0 nModified:0 upsert:1 keysInserted:2 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } storage:{} 170ms
2023-07-07T16:01:32.977+0800 I WRITE    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] update config.system.sessions command: { q: { _id: { id: UUID("21457007-6010-4e2d-9ecd-f6babf57bf59"), uid: BinData(0, 94B72FB617F98A94E1094C66354967945CDACFD4FFFE13F9C80BE90E25EFA950) } }, u: { $currentDate: { lastUse: true } }, multi: false, upsert: true } planSummary: IDHACK keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 nMatched:0 nModified:0 upsert:1 keysInserted:2 numYields:2 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 3, w: 3 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } } } storage:{} 1017ms
2023-07-07T16:01:33.936+0800 I COMMAND  [conn1] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 417ms
2023-07-07T16:01:35.243+0800 I WRITE    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] update config.system.sessions command: { q: { _id: { id: UUID("d5343c0d-1f33-47c6-b79b-be211cb9cb1f"), uid: BinData(0, 94B72FB617F98A94E1094C66354967945CDACFD4FFFE13F9C80BE90E25EFA950) } }, u: { $currentDate: { lastUse: true }, $setOnInsert: { user: { name: "tds-user@tds" } } }, multi: false, upsert: true } planSummary: IDHACK keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 nMatched:0 nModified:0 upsert:1 keysInserted:2 numYields:2 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 3, w: 3 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } } } storage:{} 1528ms
2023-07-07T16:01:37.038+0800 I COMMAND  [conn2] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 166ms
2023-07-07T16:01:37.123+0800 I COMMAND  [conn4] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 105ms
2023-07-07T16:01:37.123+0800 I COMMAND  [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 103ms
2023-07-07T16:01:37.123+0800 I COMMAND  [conn8] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 102ms
2023-07-07T16:01:37.125+0800 I COMMAND  [conn7] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 105ms
2023-07-07T16:01:37.125+0800 I COMMAND  [conn5] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 103ms
2023-07-07T16:01:37.126+0800 I COMMAND  [conn6] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 102ms
2023-07-07T16:01:37.395+0800 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 121, after asserts: 584, after backgroundFlushing: 793, after connections: 945, after dur: 1061, after extra_info: 1189, after globalLock: 1260, after locks: 1373, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 1424, after network: 1486, after opLatencies: 1535, after opReadConcernCounters: 1593, after opcounters: 1593, after opcountersRepl: 1593, after repl: 1593, after storageEngine: 1603, after tcmalloc: 1614, after transactions: 1624, after wiredTiger: 1775, at end: 1919 }
2023-07-07T16:01:38.724+0800 I WRITE    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] update config.system.sessions command: { q: { _id: { id: UUID("7ffdac56-27aa-4f88-836d-556f32ad4b70"), uid: BinData(0, 94B72FB617F98A94E1094C66354967945CDACFD4FFFE13F9C80BE90E25EFA950) } }, u: { $currentDate: { lastUse: true }, $setOnInsert: { user: { name: "tds-user@tds" } } }, multi: false, upsert: true } planSummary: IDHACK keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 nMatched:0 nModified:0 upsert:1 keysInserted:2 numYields:2 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 3, w: 3 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } } } storage:{} 2306ms
2023-07-07T16:01:39.016+0800 I COMMAND  [conn9] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 184ms
2023-07-07T16:01:39.456+0800 I WRITE    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] update config.system.sessions command: { q: { _id: { id: UUID("523f5d99-07cf-41c4-958c-241618e9dc05"), uid: BinData(0, 94B72FB617F98A94E1094C66354967945CDACFD4FFFE13F9C80BE90E25EFA950) } }, u: { $currentDate: { lastUse: true }, $setOnInsert: { user: { name: "tds-user@tds" } } }, multi: false, upsert: true } planSummary: IDHACK keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 nMatched:0 nModified:0 upsert:1 keysInserted:2 numYields:1 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } } } storage:{} 665ms
2023-07-07T16:01:39.699+0800 I COMMAND  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] command config.$cmd command: update { update: "system.sessions", ordered: false, allowImplicitCollectionCreation: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 15000 }, $db: "config" } numYields:0 reslen:651 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 25, w: 13 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 13 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 13 } } } storage:{} protocol:op_msg 8482ms
2023-07-07T16:01:43.162+0800 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 26, after asserts: 231, after backgroundFlushing: 356, after connections: 445, after dur: 515, after extra_info: 593, after globalLock: 660, after locks: 850, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 1064, after network: 1410, after opLatencies: 1547, after opReadConcernCounters: 1664, after opcounters: 1887, after opcountersRepl: 2020, after repl: 2193, after storageEngine: 2304, after tcmalloc: 2490, after transactions: 2608, after wiredTiger: 2732, at end: 2759 }
2023-07-07T16:01:48.348+0800 I COMMAND  [conn1] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 1509ms
2023-07-07T16:01:49.346+0800 I COMMAND  [conn5] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 503ms
2023-07-07T16:01:49.345+0800 I COMMAND  [conn4] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 507ms
2023-07-07T16:01:49.345+0800 I COMMAND  [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 507ms
2023-07-07T16:01:49.345+0800 I COMMAND  [conn8] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 507ms
2023-07-07T16:01:49.345+0800 I COMMAND  [conn2] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 507ms
2023-07-07T16:01:49.345+0800 I COMMAND  [conn6] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 507ms
2023-07-07T16:01:49.568+0800 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 215, after asserts: 451, after backgroundFlushing: 617, after connections: 908, after dur: 1069, after extra_info: 1291, after globalLock: 1443, after locks: 1851, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 1991, after network: 2353, after opLatencies: 2607, after opReadConcernCounters: 2856, after opcounters: 3016, after opcountersRepl: 3116, after repl: 3448, after storageEngine: 3802, after tcmalloc: 4144, after transactions: 4327, after wiredTiger: 4949, at end: 5143 }
2023-07-07T16:01:49.577+0800 I COMMAND  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] command config.system.sessions command: find { find: "system.sessions", filter: { _id: { $in: [ { id: UUID("21457007-6010-4e2d-9ecd-f6babf57bf59"), uid: BinData(0, 94B72FB617F98A94E1094C66354967945CDACFD4FFFE13F9C80BE90E25EFA950) } ] } }, projection: { _id: 1 }, batchSize: 1, singleBatch: true, limit: 1, $db: "config" } planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:1 nreturned:1 reslen:196 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } } } storage:{} protocol:op_msg 6289ms
2023-07-07T16:01:49.924+0800 I COMMAND  [conn7] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 264ms
2023-07-07T16:01:50.564+0800 I COMMAND  [conn9] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 467ms
2023-07-07T16:01:59.368+0800 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 10, after asserts: 131, after backgroundFlushing: 239, after connections: 302, after dur: 380, after extra_info: 433, after globalLock: 460, after locks: 475, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 497, after network: 653, after opLatencies: 700, after opReadConcernCounters: 724, after opcounters: 734, after opcountersRepl: 734, after repl: 744, after storageEngine: 786, after tcmalloc: 805, after transactions: 805, after wiredTiger: 938, at end: 1034 }
2023-07-07T16:02:00.366+0800 I COMMAND  [conn1] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 536ms
2023-07-07T16:02:00.687+0800 I COMMAND  [conn4] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 245ms
2023-07-07T16:02:00.687+0800 I COMMAND  [conn2] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 245ms
2023-07-07T16:02:00.688+0800 I COMMAND  [conn8] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 245ms
2023-07-07T16:02:00.687+0800 I COMMAND  [conn6] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 245ms
2023-07-07T16:02:00.688+0800 I COMMAND  [conn5] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 245ms
2023-07-07T16:02:00.688+0800 I COMMAND  [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 245ms
2023-07-07T16:02:01.338+0800 I COMMAND  [conn7] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 396ms
2023-07-07T16:02:01.825+0800 I COMMAND  [conn9] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:224 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 360ms
```

I start the mongodb service back, and If go access TDS campaign list again, it down again.
If not leave it there, then the mongodb service will not down.

Any ideas?